# How to run tcptraceroute utility on UNIX machine?

Tags: networking, tcp, trace

How can I run the `tcptraceroute` utility on a UNIX machine?
I want to run a TCP traceroute for port 80.

Comment: What UNIX variant? And what problem do you have running it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Ahsan,

By default tcptraceroute runs traceroute using tcp-syn packets for port 80. Port 80 is default. Just specify the port (by default, tcptraceroute uses port 80), and the firewall won't know the difference. Requires: libpcap, libnet, glibc packages although.

If you need any examples on using tcptraceroute utility, here are few at http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/examples.txt